# Exportación de Hoja de Excel - API - Java

Tags: java, api, excel

¿Qué API puedo utilizar para cargar datos desde una hoja de excel a una página web?

En java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la librería [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), la cual te permite leer y escribir archivos de Excel.

Particularmente la clase [`ExcelToHtmlConverter`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/converter/ExcelToHtmlConverter.html) convierte un archivo de Excel 97-2007 (`xls`) a un archivo HTML. Por ejemplo (en código):

```
try {
    Document doc = ExcelToHtmlConverter.process(new File("file.xls"));
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

En el [repositorio SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/) de Apache POI puedes encontrar otros códigos de ejemplo para convertir, ya sea `xls` o `xlsx`,